# (SQL) Optimize the selection of the relating value both to max and min

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to select the "Etotal" with Unix time being MAX and MIN. And I will need to use the MAX and MIN of "Unix time" and "Etotal" to do math later.
  But the problem is the database that I use is big ,so the method that I come out with take too much time.

Is there any way to optimize my code? Thanks for any helping hand.

Table: IV_data
 I want to select the "Etotal" with Unix time being MAX and MIN. And I will need to use the MAX and MIN of "Unix time" and "Etotal" to do math later.
  But the problem is the database that I use is big ,so the method that I come out with take too much time.

Is there any way to optimize my code? Thanks for any helping hand.

The DBMS I used is "Microsoft SQL Server"

Table: IV_data

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Unix_time      |       Etotal     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      1564588800     |         34       | <== target value1
|---------------------|------------------|
|      1564588801     |         70       |
|---------------------|------------------|
                      .
                      .
                      .
                      .
|---------------------|------------------|
|      1567008000     |         32       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      1567008001     |         80       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      1567008002     |         30       | <==target value2
|---------------------|------------------|
```

```sql
set @time_previous = (
  select MIN(da.Unix_time)
    from IV_data as da
)
set @Etotal = (
  select 
    from IV_data as da
  where
    da.Unix_time = @time_previous
)

        .
        .
    same method is applied on the MAX case
```

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: forgot to add ... "SSMS"

Comment: SSMS is not a "dbms" - it's a SQL client that connects _to_ a database server. But as it can only work with Microsoft SQL Server, it's safe to assume you are using that.

Answer (score 0):

use subquery

```
select Unix_time, Etotal from table where Unix_time= ( select min(Unix_time) from table)
or Unix_time=( select max (Unix_time) from table)
```

Comment: But if I want to use the both value later, how can I extract the value?
And thank for the help !

Comment: @JethroLeroy do you mean store procedure?

Comment: Yes, I want to do some math using these four values, but it seems that my method take a lot of time, I wonder if subquery will give better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want window functions, such as `first_value()`:

```
select t.*,
       min(unix_time) as min_ut,
       max(unix_time) as max_ut,
       first_value(etotal) over (order by unix_time asc) as etotal_at_min,
       first_value(etotal) over (order by unix_time desc) as etotal_at_max
from t;
```

If performance is an issue, an index on `(unix_time, etotal)` will help.  I do not know if you will also need one on `(unix_time desc, etotal)`.